# How to empty the $table every iteration drawn using Text::SimpleTable

Tags: perl, text

```
#!/tool/pandora64/bin/perl5.18.1
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::SimpleTable; my $a=1;my $b=2; my $c=3; my $d=4; my @p_arr = (1,2);
my $table = Text::SimpleTable->new([1, "A"], [2, "B"], [3, "C"], [4, "D"]);
foreach my $p(@p_arr){
    $table->row($a,$b,$c,$d);
    $a=$a+1; $b=$b+1; $c=$c+1; $d=$d+1;
    print "\nAfter $p iteration\n";
    print $table->draw;
}
```

I need to print the table, but after the first iteration it is appending. How can I empty the table after every iteration?

Output I get:

```
After 1 iteration
.----+----+-----+------.
| A  | B  | C   | D    |
+----+----+-----+------+
| 1  | 2  | 3   | 4    |
'----+----+-----+------'

After 2 iteration
.----+----+-----+------.
| A  | B  | C   | D    |
+----+----+-----+------+
| 1  | 2  | 3   | 4    |
| 2  | 3  | 4   | 1    |
'----+----+-----+------'
```

Expected after 1st iteration:

```
.----------------
| A | B | C | D |
+----------------
| 1 | 2 | 3  | 4 |
+----------------
```

Expected 2nd iteration:

```
.----------------
| A | B | C | D |
+----------------
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move the call to `new` inside the `foreach` loop.  This creates a new table each time through the loop:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::SimpleTable; my $a=1;my $b=2; my $c=3; my $d=4; my @p_arr = (1,2);
foreach my $p(@p_arr){
    my $table = Text::SimpleTable->new([1, "A"], [2, "B"], [3, "C"], [4, "D"]);
    $table->row($a,$b,$c,$d);
    $a=$a+1; $b=$b+1; $c=$c+1; $d=$d+1;
    print "\nAfter $p iteration\n";
    print $table->draw;
}
```

Prints:

```
After 1 iteration
.----+----+-----+------.
| A  | B  | C   | D    |
+----+----+-----+------+
| 1  | 2  | 3   | 4    |
'----+----+-----+------'

After 2 iteration
.----+----+-----+------.
| A  | B  | C   | D    |
+----+----+-----+------+
| 2  | 3  | 4   | 5    |
'----+----+-----+------'
```

---

If you want the width of all the columns to be the same, you can use the same number in the call to `new`:

```
my $table = Text::SimpleTable->new([1, "A"], [1, "B"], [1, "C"], [1, "D"]);
```

The [POD](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::SimpleTable) doesn't specify what the arguments to `new` are, so I had to look at the source code.